# Need help writing a IF/Then SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have a table called Plate which is where I can view the quantity of inventory in my warehouse (all inventory is stored on License Plates). My current query looks at all plates in certain plate statuses, and sums the quantity:

```sql
    select custitemalias.itemalias, custitem.item, custitem.baseuom, sum(plate.quantity), plate.facility, plate.invstatus
    from custitem
    left join plate ON PLATE.ITEM=custitem.item
    left join CUSTITEMALIAS on custitem.item=CUSTITEMALIAS.ITEM
    where custitem.custid ='CUSTOMER'
    and plate.invstatus = 'AV'
    and plate.status !='P'
    group by custitemalias.itemalias, custitem.item, plate.facility, plate.invstatus, custitem.baseuom
```

The problem with this query is that it will look at plates that have inventory status of AV (available). If there is none in AV, but some in another status say OH (on hold), i'd like the query to report a 0 or null.

So

```sql
    IF plate.invstatus = 'AV' and plate.quantity <1
    THEN plate.quantity ="0"
```

I'm striking out on how to write this, likely because of the sum of the quanity, any help?

Comment: IF/THEN is likely the wrong syntax for what you want to do. You need to tag the RDBMS for your question to be answered. Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Depending on the DBMS system, a CASE type expression is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: `sum(CASE WHEN plate.invstatus = 'AV' and  plate.quantity >= 1 THEN plate.quantity END)`

Comment: There is no `IF` in standard SQL. The closest thing is a CASE expression.